# SQL Distinct limitation

Tags: sql

i Have a table that contain coordinates info...like this:

```
Li_from
----------
36.2090536962569;37.1511090538763
36.2130356969589;37.1443713448309
36.2130876347598;37.1508944771551
36.2093999652314;37.1442425987982
36.2130356969589;37.1443713448309
36.2130356969589;37.1443713448309
```

and when i want to select distinct values from the column above like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Li_from from table.
```

the result is the same as above although the last two values are identical ..
so is there limitation for the distinct keyword , and how can i select distinct values??

Comment: How are those values being stored, and how are you displaying them?

Comment: Most certainly, they are _not_ identical as far as the DBMS is concerned. Perhaps one has trailing spaces?

Comment: Also, are you sure those values dont contain trailing spaces or other non display characters?

Comment: they are stored as string values

Comment: and how to make sure for the trailing spaces and other display characters, i'm newbie in this stuff?

Comment: Please see my answer - LTRIM and RTRIM are in most DBMS's.

Comment: This is a bad design.  Store the coordinates in separate columns with the correct (eg `numeric` or `double`) data type for each column.

Comment: copy-paste the values from the result grid to a pair of empty quotes ''; then you will see any trailing spaces and stuff

Comment: Or if using `SQL 2008 R2` onwards you could store them in a `geography` datatype

Comment: Or Oracle Spatial for Oracle 9i+

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure the last two columns are *identical*? Have you tried `SELECT DISTINCT LTRIM(RTRIM(Li_from)) from table`?

This will remove leading and trailing space characters.

Comment: yup , it worked, it seemed that there were white spaces.thanks a lot